# Need to create a knowledge user in test class

Tags: apex

I need to create a Knowledge user in the test class for publishing the Article.Please let me know if there is a way to create one.

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, it can be helpful to include what you've tried or done so far as I have no clue what level of detail you might need.

For permissions for knowledge, there's one field you need to set to "true" and that's "userPermissionsKnowledgeUser".

```
 testUser.UserPermissionsKnowledgeUser = true;
```

Otherwise, the required fields when creating a user in apex are the following and will also need to be set

- LastName
- TimeZoneSidKey
- LocaleSidKey
- EmailEncodingKey
- LanguageLocaleKey
- username
- email
- alias
- UserRoleId
- ProfileId
- IsActive